# systemd-boot skips boot menu and ignores settings in /loader/loader.conf

Tags: boot, uefi, nixos, systemd-boot

Recently, after I've done something to my multiboot system, when I boot NixOS with `systemd-boot`, boot menu does not show up anymore even though the timeout is still set to 2 seconds in `/loader/loader.conf` (on the ESP):

```
# /loader/loader.conf on the ESP
timeout 2
default nixos-generation-380
```

Here is what I have in my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
{ # ...
  boot.loader = {
    efi.canTouchEfiVariables = true;
    systemd-boot.enable = true;
    timeout = 2;
  };
}
```

It turned out that to see the boot menu, I had to press down some key during start-up, as if the timeout had been set to 0 (instead of 2) seconds.

I tried removing `systemd-bootx64.efi` from the ESP and re-installing NixOS with `nixos-install` from a USB flash drive.  This restored `systemd-bootx64.efi` but did not bring back the boot menu.

It seems that this problem is not completely uncommon:

- Reddit: [systemd-boot menu suddenly disappeared?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/6e0q1e)
- Arch Linux Forums: [systemd-boot, no timeout, no select menu - LoaderEntryDefault](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229486)

Both issues are reported to be solved.  However, I did not understand the first solution:

> Edit 3: SOLVED! Reinstalling the UEFI did the trick.

What does it mean to "reinstall the UEFI"?

As to the second, it suggests to use <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> keys in the boot menu (which shows up if some key is pressed down during the start-up) to set a different timeout, but I do not want just a different timeout, I want `systemd-boot` to respect the settings in `/loader/loader.conf`.

So, my question was: how to make `systemd-boot` use again the settings from `/loader/loader.conf`?

I am editing this question after I've found the solution, and I am going to post my answer now.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the timeout? The default value is 5, but you can also set it null to disable the timeout entirely. Regarding your triple-boot system, which EFI boot manager are you using? Is it possible that NixOS kernel is being booted via a boot manager other than the systemd-boot provided by NixOS?

Comment: Your EFI setup looks OK. In your ESP you should have (/boot)/loader/loader.conf, which is your main systemd-boot configuration. What does it look like? You should see your timeout setting from /etc/nixos/configuration.nix reflected in loader.conf.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, i've found a solution, so i am cleaning up the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [comment #6](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1733461#p1733461) on ["systemd-boot, no timeout, no select menu - LoaderEntryDefault"](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229486) and looking at ["systemd-boot sets efivar LoaderEntryDefault, which overrides default in /boot/loader/loader.conf"](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/28445) `nixpkgs` issue on GitHub, I've figured out that the issue was probably caused by EFI variables which somehow got set and were overriding the settings from `/loader/loader.conf`.

Indeed, there were these two variables set that were causing trouble:

```
§ cat /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderConfigTimeout-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f
0
```

and

```
§ cat /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderEntryDefault-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f
nixos-generation-374
```

(I've made up the value '`374`' here: it only matters that it was different from the one in `/loader/loader.conf` at the time when I inspected it.)

The list of EFI variable used by `systemd-boot` can be found at the end of ["systemd-boot UEFI Boot Manager"](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/systemd-boot/) page on [Freedesktop Wiki](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/):

```
LoaderEntryDefault      entry identifier to select as default at bootup                  non-volatile
LoaderConfigTimeout     timeout in seconds to show the menu                              non-volatile
LoaderEntryOneShot      entry identifier to select at the next and only the next bootup  non-volatile
LoaderDeviceIdentifier  list of identifiers of the volume the loader was started from    volatile
LoaderDevicePartUUID    partition GPT UUID of the ESP systemd-boot was executed from     volatile
```

To remove `LoaderEntryDefault-[...]` variable it was enough to press <kbd>d</kbd> key twice in the boot menu: to set and unset a new value.

To remove `LoaderConfigTimeout-[...]` variable it turned out enough to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> enough times to set the timeout to `0`, plus one more time.

This resolved my problem.  Here is a related [question](https://superuser.com/q/1346163) I asked on Superuser.SE about safely modifying EFI variables in general.

Comment: It was so unexpected that UEFI stores that default value. And it was so simple to select a new default)) Thanks for your research!

Comment: How to press shift+t in the boot menu if the boot menu isn't shown?

Comment: @zoechi, I do not remember what I did exactly, but I guess you need to press these keys during start-up.